Всë, что нужно, – это тире, или запятая тоже?
Есть у нас следующее предложение: «Да, и чтобы нанести травму такого типа, всë, что нужно, – это плоский предмет, так?»
Никак не могу понять, нужно ли перед словом "это" использовать сочетание запятой и тире, либо же достаточно только одного знака.
Буду очень признателен за ответ и пояснение!

ВСТУПЛЕНИЕ
Посмотрите ответы Справочной службы по сходной теме.
Пунктуация зависит от контекста, то есть для каждого случая свое решение. Например, в значении «хороший, самый лучший» корректно: то что надо. В этом случае придаточное считается устойчивым оборотом.
Но все зависит от семантики и структуры предложения.  С другой стороны, на практике много примеров с упрощенным оформлением темы, например: все, что надо — это... В то же время желательно как-то сочетать норму и практику письма.
РЕШЕНИЕ
(1) Лучше оставить как есть:
«Да, и чтобы нанести травму такого типа, всë, что нужно, — это плоский предмет, так?»
(2) Допускается такой вариант:
«Да, и чтобы нанести травму такого типа, всë что надо — это плоский предмет, так?»
Здесь всё что надо — устойчивый оборот со значением "всё необходимое".
